# What is wrong with the syntax of this insert statement?

Tags: mysql

What is wrong with the syntax of this insert statement?

```
INSERT INTO  products (`gallery_img`)
VALUES ('gwnnrjnsdknjsdkjnkjnsdnjvnksdvsdv')
WHERE name = 'Gmamble';
```

Comment: INSERT is for new data.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about rudimentary SQL

Comment: @Wesley, if you're stating that SQL isn't primarily used by developers, I have to disagree. And if you're stating it's too rudimentary, I also have to disagree - SO is meant for ALL skill levels. By all means close as a dupe or close as "not enough research" if either of those are the case, but I don't think off-topic is the right reason.

Comment: @paxdiablo It's merely semantics. "Off-topic" encapsulates questions that don't show a reasonable amount of research. I did not expect to find a dupe because this is a rather low quality question, with questionable value to future visitors.

Comment: @paxdiablo I think I understand your confusion, my second comment was auto-generated by the system. I don't mean to say that SQL is off topic (of course), I mean that the question is far too basic and shows zero effort or research, not even an error message.

Comment: No, that's okay, @Wesley, it's just that you appear to have selected your own reason "rudimentary SQL" when there's already a canned "not enough research" reason on the list. It probably could have done with some extra looking into before asking but since you now state that's the real reason, I understand.

Answer (score 5):

You insert *new* data, meaning that a `where` clause is irrelevant because it's not yet in the table. That would be something along the lines of:

```
insert into people (name, property)
  values ('paxdiablo', 'good-looking')
```

If you want to change *current* data, you use update, where the `where` clause makes sense:

```
update people
  set property = 'good-looking AND intelligent'
  where name = 'paxdiablo'
```

For your particular case, it would be:

```
update products
  set gallery_img = 'gwnnrjnsdknjsdkjnkjnsdnjvnksdvsdv'
  where name = 'Gmamble'
```

Comment: @user814064: sure, added a couple more example to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: @user814064, the best AND good-looking AND ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

you cant use where condition with insert statement

if you wish to insert some values from tbl_temp2 in to tbl_temp1 then use following syntax

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE, DELETE, AND SELECT statement can use WHERE clause, Do not use WHERE clause in INSERT statement because it is for inserting a new row.